# H2 - An illegal reflective access operation has occurred

Tags: java, spring-boot, entity, h2

After starting my spring-boot app a warning-

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper (file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.3.7.Final/hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar) to field java.lang.String.coder
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Has a result my table has a Coder column instead of the actual name like my Entity -

```
@Entity
public class TaxValuesEntity {

    @EmbeddedId
    public String countryCodePK;
    public double taxValue;
    public Timestamp creationAt;
    public Timestamp modifedAt;

    protected TaxValuesEntity() {
    };

    public TaxValuesEntity(String countryCode, double taxValue, Timestamp creation, Timestamp modifed) {
        this.countryCodePK = countryCode;
        this.taxValue = taxValue;
        this.creationAt = creation;
        this.modifedAt = modifed;
    }
    //getters & setters ...
};
```

Thank's for any help and please comment below if more code needed.

Comment: What Java and Spring boot version?

Comment: Open JDK 11, forgot to write it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue with JDK11 and Mockito. The fix was to use latest version of Mockito. Maybe check the version of Hibernate and the current support status for JDK 11. On a quick search, found this [using hibernate with jdk11](http://in.relation.to/2018/09/13/using-hibernate-orm-with-jdk11/.) and [hibernate release 5.4](http://hibernate.org/orm/releases/5.4/)

Comment: Well after changing the project to JDK 8 the error resolved. I will wait for JDK 11 updates.

Comment: It seems 5.4 is stable and supports it, if you feel like experimenting :).

Comment: Not really, I will postpone this issue, for now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `EmbeddedId` with `Id` like this:

```
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class TaxValuesEntity {

    @Id
    public String countryCodePK;
```

`EmbeddedId` is for composite primary key.